# ManagedBeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I have Users pojo and this pojo is not extend from T.It is like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "USERS.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM USERS s")})
public class USERS implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected USERSPK usersPK;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private Stirng name;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "Surname")
    private String surname;
```

And I wanted to select smth.from this table.Service and DAO classes are below:

```
public interface CommonService {

    public List<Object> hepsiniGetir2(Class persistenceClass, String property, Object searchCrit);

}
```

This is implementation of interface;

```
 @Service("commonService")
    public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService, Serializable {
    @Transactional
        public List<Object> hepsiniGetir2(Class persistenceClass, String property, Object searchCrit) {
            return commonDao.findAllByCrit2(persistenceClass, property, searchCrit);
        }
    }
```

And here dao interface:

```
public interface CommonDAO extends GenericDAO<TemelNesne, Long> {
   public List<Object> findAllByCrit2(Class persistenceClass, String property, Object searchCrit);

}
```

Here implementation of dao class:

```
@Repository
public class CommonDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<TemelNesne, Long> implements CommonDAO {
  public List findAllByCrit2(Class persistenceClass, String property, Object searchCrit) {
        Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
                createCriteria(persistenceClass).add(Restrictions.eq(property, searchCrit));
        List<Object> list = c.list();

        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return list;
        }
    }



}
```

In view class I call this method like ;

```
@ManagedBean(name="userView", eager=true)
@ViewScoped
public class UserView extends BaseView implements Serializable {
@ManagedProperty("#{commonService}")
    private CommonService commonService;
    private List<USERS> list;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = (List) commonService.hepsiniGetir2(USERS.class, "name", "Deniz");
    }
}
```

Lastly, I had this exception:

> Tem 04, 2014 5:38:10 PM
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy
>   handleRenderException SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/userList.xhtml]
>   com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred
>   performing resource injection on managed bean userView Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
>   Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:
>   3C3F786D

Comment: This problem isn't related to Hibernate at all, is about JSF + Spring integration.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a concept problem. JSF beans cannot autowire Spring beans, nor the other way around. This is because they are managed in different containers. You should integrate Spring with JSF to allow injection, which basically boils down to Spring controlling everything. There are plenty tutorials in the net about doing this. One good tutorial is mkyong's: [JSF 2 + Spring 3 Integration Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/). Basically, these are the steps (taken from his tutorial):

- In faces-config.xml file, add Expression Language (EL) resolver:

  ```xml
  <application>
      <el-resolver>
              org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
      </el-resolver>
  </application>
  ```
- Instead using JSF annotations, use Spring annotations for JSF managed beans. Example applied to your classes:

  ```
  @Component("userView")
  @Scope("view")
  public class UserView extends BaseView implements Serializable {
      @Autowired
      private CommonService commonService;
      private List<USERS> list;

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
         list = (List) commonService.hepsiniGetir2(Sertifikalar.class, "name", "Deniz");
     }
  }
  ```

Note that in this example, I'm using `@Scope("view")` but [Spring doesn't have a view scope by default, the team is still working on it](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6543). You have to implement this scope manually. Fortunately, you can use [Cagatay's implementation](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) to solve this.

Apart of these problems, you have another conceptual problem: the only bean that supports `eager=true` is `@ApplicationScoped` since it will work as a `@Singleton` Spring bean, other managed beans will ignore this attribute **at all**.

Comment: Thank you @Luiggi, i tried to solve annotation problems,nevertheless my real problem still continues